# Php simple algorithm for autoloader

Tags: php, autoload

Here's my "simple" algorithm:

- if the class is named like '`AaaBbbCccDddEeeFff`' loop like this:

  - `include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.php`
  - `include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee_fff.php`
  - `include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd_eee_fff.php`
  - `include/aaa/bbb/ccc_ddd_eee_fff.php`
  - `include/aaa/bbb_ccc_ddd_eee_fff.php`
  - `include/aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee_fff.php`
- if still nothing found, try to look if those files exist:

  - `include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/base.php`
  - `include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/base.php`
  - `include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/base.php`
  - `include/aaa/bbb/ccc/base.php`
  - `include/aaa/bbb/base.php`
  - `include/aaa/base.php`
  - `include/base.php`

If still not found then error.

I'm looking for a fast and easy way to convert this:

'`AaaBbbCccDddEeeFff`'

to this:

`include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.php`

and then and easy way to remove latest folder (I guess I should look for `explode()`).

Any idea how to do this? (I'm not asking for the whole code, I'm not lazy).

Comment: No need to re-invent your own autoloading algorithm. You should use existing ones such as `PSR-0`, or `PSR-4`. And yes - yours looks like PSR-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specifically asked not to have the whole code, here is some code to get you started. This takes the input and divides it into chunks delineated by changes in case. The rest you can work out as an exercise.

```
<?php
    $input = "AaaBbbCccDddEeeFff";
    $str_so_far = "";
    $last_was_upper = 0;
    $chunks = array(); 
    while($next_letter = substr($input,0,1)) {
        $is_upper = (strtoupper($next_letter)==$next_letter);
        if($str_so_far && $is_upper && !$last_was_upper) {
            $chunks[] = $str_so_far;
            $str_so_far = "";
        }
        if($str_so_far && !$is_upper && $last_was_upper) {
            $chunks[] = $str_so_far;
            $str_so_far = "";
        }
        $str_so_far .= $next_letter;
        $input = substr($input,1);
        $last_was_upper = $is_upper;
    }
    var_dump($chunks);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a regular expression would work. Something like `preg_match_all('[A-Z][a-z][a-z]'
, $string);` might work - that would match a capital letter, followed by a lowercase letter, and another lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first part of your algorithm:

> AaaBbbCccDddEeeFff -> 
> include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.php 
>   include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee_fff.php
>   include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd_eee_fff.php
>   include/aaa/bbb/ccc_ddd_eee_fff.php
>   include/aaa/bbb_ccc_ddd_eee_fff.php
>   include/aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee_fff.php

I think you can do last part independently based on my answer.

```
<?php

function convertClassToPath($class) {
    return strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '$2', $class)) . '.php';
}

function autoload($path) {
    $base_dir = 'include' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $real_path = $base_dir  . $path;
    var_dump('Checking: ' . $real_path);
    if (file_exists($real_path) === true) {
        var_dump('Status: Success');
        include $real_path;
    } else {
        var_dump('Status: Fail');
        $last_separator_pos = strrpos($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        if ($last_separator_pos === false) {
            return;
        } else {
            $path = substr_replace($path, '_', $last_separator_pos, 1);
            autoload($path);                
        }

    }
}

$class = 'AaaBbbCccDddEeeFff';
var_dump(autoload(convertClassToPath($class)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers are regex, here's a non-regex way for completeness:

```
function transform($str){
    $arr = array();
    $part = '';
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
        $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
        if(ctype_upper($char) && $i > 0){
            $arr[] = $part;
            $part = '';
        }
        $part .= $char;
    }
    $arr[] = $part;

    return 'include/' . strtolower(implode('/', $arr)) . '.php';
}

echo transform('AaaBbbCccDddEeeFff');
// include/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff.php
```

This builds an array of the folders, so you can manipulate it as needed, for example remove a folder by unsetting the desired index, before it gets imploded.